# getting values from database as an option value using php

Tags: php, html

So i was doing our thesis and i need to transfer some values from my sql database to my

here's the sample code:

```
    <tr>
        <td id="t" align="center">Subject: <select name="subj">
        <?php 
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
        if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $db_selected = mysql_select_db("sps_ccp",$con);
        $college=$_SESSION['college1'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM subject_db WHERE crs='$college'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
        //echo $count;
        for($ctr=0;$ctr<$count;$ctr++)
        {
        $sql1="SELECT subject FROM subject_db WHERE crs='$college'";
        $subj=mysql_query($sql1,$con);
        $subj1=mysql_result($subj,$ctr);
        echo "<option value=".$subj1.">".$subj1."</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select>
</td>
```

And also i have this option where i have to get that option value then it'll search through my database and get that value and put it in another option.

here's the sample code:

```
<tr>
    <td id="t">Building: <select name="build">
    <option value="hr">HR Building</option>
    <option value="pr">PR Building</option>
    <option value="gv">GV Building</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td id="t">Room: <select name="room">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['build'])){

        if($_POST['build']=='hr')
        {
            $hr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hrbuilding");
            $h1 = mysql_num_rows($hr);
            while(mysql_fetch_array($hr)){
            if(h1>0)
            {   
                echo "<option value=".$hr.">".$hr."</option>";

            }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    </td>
```

Both didn't worked. It didn't have values on the option box. I did checked my database and I don't think that there are any problems with it. I asked someone on how to work on this but he suggested to use javascript which i really couldn't understand how it works.
Hoping you could help me :) thanks!

Comment: What results are you getting? Are you printing out error messages?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham I'm just getting values for an option box. Should I get a picture? I'm really not good with explaining stuffs. I'm not printing error messages just trying to get values from the database for a conditional statement.

Comment: At least describe what didn't work. Did you get the wrong values? No values?

Comment: Step 1: write `error_reporting(1)` at the top of your php file. Step 2: put checks at each step (each if statement) to see if you're actually reaching there. Ex: after if(isset($_post['build'])) make a line `echo "Variable build is set";`. This will let you see what stages your program is reaching.

Comment: Sidenote: The first one may not have worked because of missing `session_start();` which is required when using sessions.

Comment: And your second one is this `if(h1>0)` which should read as `if($h1 > 0)` you left out the `$` sign.

Answer (score 0):

The first body of code may not have worked because of the missing `session_start();` which is required when using [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). Since it's required to be at the top, you stand at getting an error stating that `headers already sent...` therefore you will need to either seperate your HTML from PHP, having PHP on top, or placing `ob_start();` on top of `session_start();`

Your second body of code is most likely failing because of this `if(h1>0)` which should read as `if($h1 > 0)` you left out the `$` sign.

Plus, in your first body of code, you are missing the password parameter in: (*if it's not a typo*)

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
```

which should read as:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
```

Example taken from http://www.php.net/mysql_connect

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

**N.B.:** Do consider switching to `mysqli_*` functions. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future releases.

Comment: Thanks i tried it but still it the option box didn't have a value.

Comment: You're welcome. You also need to have `<form>...</form>` tags which I don't see in your code. Are you using them? @JessicaJoy

Comment: Also this line `echo "<option value=".$hr.">".$hr."</option>";` should probably look like `echo "<option value='".$hr."'>".$hr."</option>";` or `echo "<option value=\".$hr.\">".$hr."</option>";` @JessicaJoy

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error here:
You get the results from query, yet you're calling again the same query but without actually getting the fields (merely the query's resource). There's also a missing quote from `value` attribute.

To fix:

```
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("sps_ccp",$con);
    $college=$_SESSION['college1'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM subject_db WHERE crs='$college'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    //echo $count;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo '<option value="'.$row["subject"].'">'.$row["subject"].'</option>';
    }
```

Also when using sessions in a file, make sure that you're calling [session_start](http://www.php.net/session_start) and this must be the top position of your file, since it is a header-send call.

Also in your second code block you forgot to put a dollar in front of `h1` variable.

**EDIT**

```
// very top of file
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// now, just call your PHP code but in between 2 calls
ob_start();

...call your PHP code here

$buffer = ob_get_clean();
echo $buffer;    // what is here? place it so you can see on screen what it says
```

Comment: Thanks i tried it but still it the option box still didn't have a value. >.<

Comment: I'm guessing now but what is the value of `$college` that comes from the session? Can you print it? Is that value a valid (existent) `crs` field at all? Can you hard-code a value just to see if it works, instead of session? Can you use the [output buffering](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) functions i edited my answer with?

Answer (score 0):

hope this may help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="sample_s">
        <?php
            mysql_connect("localhost","root","your_password");
            mysql_select_db("db_name");
            if(mysql_errno())
            die("Database Server is Offline");
            $q=mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `opt` FROM `sample`");
            if(mysql_num_rows($q)){
                while($m=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$m["opt"].'">'.$m["opt"].'</option>';
                }        
            }    
        ?>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks i tried it but still it the option box still didn't have a value. >.<